How to find Casimir operator eigenvalues of $SU(N)$?

The $[f1, f2, f3…fn]$ in the image represent the irreducible representations of $SU[n]$. How to find the irreducible representations of $SU[n]$ that conform to the form $[f1, f2...fn]$. Can you give me the irreducible representations of $SU(4)?$

How to obtain the expression of Casimir operator.




Do you understand how partitions (Young diagrams) lable the irreducible representations? If not you need to read up on this topic.

You never identified your undisclosed reference. You do not compute the Casimirs. You (as a student) look them up in Slansky's review. Run to it.

For the partitions, if n=4, which has 5 irreducible representations, such as [4],[31],[22],[211],[1111]. If I chose [31], f1=3,f2=1,f3=0,f4=0. Do I understand correctly?
